# Stop Windows Exporer from spinning up E: drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer

I'm trying to find out what is causing the second drive in a Windows 10 system to spin up. I've disabled paging, defragmenting and indexing on that drive, and put it into the exclusions list of Windows Defender.

But, lo and behold, lowly `explorer.exe` is messing with it, as evidenced by this event log which occurred around the time of a spurious spin up:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          2020-09-24 12:55:53 PM
Event ID:      4656
Task Category: File System
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-K8055OB
Description:
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
    Security ID:        DESKTOP-K8055OB\kaz
    Account Name:       kaz
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-K8055OB
    Logon ID:       0x19B1C

Object:
    Object Server:      Security
    Object Type:        File
    Object Name:        E:\
    Handle ID:      0x162c
    Resource Attributes:    -

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0xf00
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Access Request Information:
    Transaction ID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Accesses:       SYNCHRONIZE
                ReadData (or ListDirectory)
                ReadAttributes
                
    Access Reasons:     SYNCHRONIZE:    Granted by  D:(A;;0x1301bf;;;AU)
                ReadData (or ListDirectory):    Granted by  D:(A;;0x1301bf;;;AU)
                ReadAttributes: Granted by  D:(A;;0x1301bf;;;AU)
                
    Access Mask:        0x100081
    Privileges Used for Access Check:   -
    Restricted SID Count:   0
```

There is one Explorer window open showing just "This PC > Documents". It is not being explored.

How can I find out why Explorer does this, and how can it be stopped?

Comment: I am looking for an answer for you.. but in the meantime.. The system internals process monitor might be of use here.. at least you could see WHAT it was doing which might give you a better clue as to WHY it was doing it. ?? And yes, this sucks.

Comment: Do you have OneDrive or similar cloud access? Since "SYNCHRONIZE" is listed, you might try disabling drive sync services. BTW, I've noticed the first time I try to save a file with MS File Save dialog, it spins up other drives, *even though I've not tried saving to an external drive*.